# Displaying 5 thumbnails at a time horizontally

Tags: css, sass

I need a bit of help figuring out some styling for a thumbnail-container. With this current styling:

```
#modal-window.full-gallery {
  max-width: 961px;

.thumbnail-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height:64px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

.sp-thumbnail {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin-right: 7px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    border: 0;
  }
}
```

This is the results of the above styling when I switch to mobile view:
[image]

When I view it in mobile it squishes all 10 thumbnails, but I want it to just show five at a time with the two at both edges of the view to only show half the image, like its cut off, like so:
[image]

I tried this:

```
.thumbnail-container {
    margin: 30px auto;
    width: 80%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```

but that gives me two columns of five thumbnails side by side in mobile view, in other words two vertical columns of five thumbnails like so:
[image]

I will probably need to do this inside a media query because this does affect the desktop view, but I can fix that, I am just not sure how to get to display five out of the 10 thumbnails with two looking like they are cutting off at the edges of the mobile view.

And to clarify a bit more, this is a modal feature. The html for it is:

```
<div class="modal-info">
  <div class="modal_message">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="content-container">

        <div class="thumbnail-container">
          <button class="sp-thumbnail magic ada-el-focus" data-action="card-magic" title="View the Magic card"></button>
          <button class="sp-thumbnail th ada-el-focus" data-action="card-th" title="View the Celebration card"></button>
          <button class="sp-thumbnail ice-cream ada-el-focus" data-action="card-ice-cream" title="View the ice-cream card"></button>
          <button class="sp-thumbnail yoga ada-el-focus" data-action="card-yoga" title="View the Yoga card"></button>
          <button class="sp-thumbnail gaia ada-el-focus" data-action="card-gaia" title="View the Gaia card"></button>
          <button class="sp-thumbnail bbq ada-el-focus" data-action="card-bbq" title="View the BBQ card"></button>
          <button class="sp-thumbnail pinker ada-el-focus" data-action="card-pinker" title="View the Pink card"></button>
          <button class="sp-thumbnail spotlight ada-el-focus" data-action="card-spotlight" title="View the Spotlight card"></button>
          <button class="sp-thumbnail pals ada-el-focus" data-action="card-pals" title="View the Pals card"></button>
          <button class="sp-thumbnail father ada-el-focus" data-action="card-father" title="View the father card"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So I am not sure if I can just take care of all this in `thumbnail-container` or a I need to tweak some things in `sp-thumbnail` as well. I keep trying different things, but I am just all over the place and not getting the result I want.

So you could say, I don't want whats inside the `thumbnail-container` to be responsive. Let me explain, I want the images to resize upon resizing the view, but as the view gets smaller I want the thumbnails to cut off at the edges of the view.

Comment: Add a [mcve] please.

Comment: @KoshVery, I added some examples of whats going on with each styling and my desired expectation is.

Comment: can you add your html?

Comment: @YashwardhanPauranik, I added the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for your `thumbnail-container` I would leave the `display: flex` but I would get rid of the other flex type properties. Flex is definitely making this difficult for you.

So it would look like this:

```
.thumbnail-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height:64px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
```

and for `sp-thumbnail` I would change the `width:` to `min-width: 20%;` Flex is notorious for blowing off `width`. It's much more receptive to `min-width`.

Give all that a try.